# leaflet.js jquery UI Tabs: Prevent background map scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui, leaflet

Please see this: http://gisdev.clemson.edu/fireflies/

On the top right is jquery ui Tab component. As you can see, clicking inside the tab component makes the background map to scroll. I have tried things like: `opacity:1` and also tried this code:

```
      $( "#tabs" ).click(function() {
        return false;
      });
```

But nothing is working.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by making a custom component, as seen here:

https://github.com/ngageoint/geoq/blob/develop/geoq/core/static/core/js/leafletcontrols/leaflet.simple_button.js

Used like:

https://github.com/ngageoint/geoq/blob/develop/geoq/core/static/core/js/aoi_feature_edit.js#L320-L329

This has a few lines that catch the events on the control and stop them from propogating to the map beneath it:

```
onAdd: function (map) {
  this._map = map;
  var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-button');

  L.DomEvent.on(container, 'mousedown', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
    .on(container, 'doubleclick', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
    .on(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
```

Comment: Sorry, just finding your Answer; never got the email notification and I had given up on this. Will try your solution soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have used your suggestion and fixed this problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet's `L.DomEvent` has a `disableClickPropagation` method that:

> Adds stopPropagation to the element's 'click', 'doubleclick',
>   'mousedown' and 'touchstart' events.

In addition to the `disableClickPropagation`, you also need to add a listener to the `wheel` event to stop the propagation.

```
var customControl = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function (map) {
      var div = L.DomUtil.create('div','custom-control');
      L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
      L.DomEvent.addListener(l, 'wheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
      return div;
    }
});
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domevent

Answer (score 0):

Per JayCrossler's comment, I have this code which (mostly) takes care of this problem. Thanks Jay!

```
  $( "#tabs" ).click(function() {
      var container = this; // this = 'tabs' div
      L.DomEvent.on(container, 'mousedown', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation).on(container, 'doubleclick', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation).on(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
  });
```